# CMD gives error Feature Name Microsoft-Hyper-V Is Unknown

Tags: hyper-v, hypervisor, hyper-virtualization

I tried to disable Hyper-V in the Command Prompt and it gave this error :

```
Feature Name Microsoft-Hyper-V Is Unknown
```

The Hyper-V has not been disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Open **elevated command prompt** and run `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off` and restart

If that doesn't work, try this instead:

- Open `optionalfeatures.exe` and un-check Hyper-V

Hope this helps!